# Why is ssh via a ProxyCommand slows down the terminal on the target server?

Tags: linux, ssh

Earlier I used to use ssh key forwarding to ssh into the private EC2 instances via a bastion host as follows:

```
Host dev
   HostName 53.209.163.67
   User ubuntu
   IdentityFile ~/Documents/Keys/dev.pem
   ForwardAgent yes
   ProxyCommand none
```

But I realized that the key forwarding is not safe and then I switched to using the ProxyCommand as follows:

```
Host dev1.dev dev2.dev         
  IdentityFile ~/Documents/Keys/dev.pem
  HostName %h
  User ubuntu         
  ProxyCommand ssh -i ~/Documents/Keys/dev.pem -W %h:%p ubuntu@3.306.119.101
```

I'm able to run the command `ssh dev1.dev` and connect to the target server but then the commands I type or run on the target servers are extremely slow.

Why is it so? Any kind of help will be grately appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try setting `UseDNS` to `no` in `/etc/sshd_config` or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: @harrymc on bastion host or local pc?

Comment: `sshd` is on the server.